# How to define type of a global variable in a library based on its configuration variables?

Tags: node.js, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I am trying to write a library that defines some variable in the global scope. So in Typescript, I can use `declare global` to provide the type for that global variable.

However, in my case, the type of that global variable will depend upon how my library is configured, i.e., it depends on the types of some configuration variables. Is there a way I can achieve the same? Maybe using generics somehow? Or any other way would do.

If typescript doesn't support it natively, I'm also open to know if (and how) one can write a typescript plugin for the same.

Thank you in advance :)

Comment: Could you give a more concrete example of what you are trying to achieve? TS is pretty extensible, we have open ended interfaces and module augmentation for example, which allow for extensibility of libraries. TS plugins are not an option, they do not allow you to change types (plugins can change emit, but you can't load them into the stock compiler anyway)